# Why active scaffold form gets broken after assets precompile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

Why active scaffold links(e.g.: Create, Edit, Show, etc.) are not working after assets precompile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me as well - very frustrating indeed. 
With Rails 3.2 and ActiveScaffold, after pre-compiling assets, all AJAX based forms generated by ActiveScaffold stopped working "in-place".
Note that the forms still work fine if you load them in the browser directly as "localhost:3000///edit" etc.

It has to do with the sequence in which javascript was loaded in the application.js file. We had to make sure that jquery_ujs is at the end. After making the change, our application.js looks like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require_tree 
//= require active_scaffold
//= require jquery.tipsy.js
//= require jquery.dcmegamenu.1.3.3.js
//= require jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Then run rake assets:precompile and everything works fine.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution and everything works as expected. Thanks a lot to get rid of this problem!